# Making a site mobile friendly

Tags: php, iphone, html, mobile-phones

Is there a way to make it so when a site is viewed with a phone or other small mobile device the site automatically recognizes that it is being viewed as such and either re-directs to a phone friendly subdomain mirror or automatically calls a script that makes it phone friendly?

Any articles or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`user-agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers) in the HTTP request can help detect the browser. You can then redirect to the subdomain when the page is viewed from specific browsers.

Otherwise, the [`media`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-intro) CSS selector can be used as well to adapt the layout to the kind of device. There is media type `handheld`, but I don't know how well it is supported.

Comment: *Slaps forehead* great idea! I'll have to research some popular mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple CSS.

```
<link href="/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Comment: This assumes the site is mobile-ready except for the CSS. If there's a bunch of Flash, huge images, etc., this isn't as good a solution as a dedicated mobile site they get redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, certainly you can use JavaScript code to check what kind of browsers that the users run, and respond appropiately to that. For example :

```
var browser = navigator.appName;

if (browser == 'Mozilla Firefox') {
 // do something
} else if (browser == 'Some Weird Browser') {
 // do something else
}
```

Reference : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that can help you detect mobile browsers. Here's some sample PHP code:

```
function isMobileBrowser() {

  if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"])) return true;

    if(preg_match("/wap\.|\.wap/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"])) return true;

    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){

      // Quick Array to kill out matches in the user agent
      // that might cause false positives

      $badmatches = array("OfficeLiveConnector","MSIE\ 8\.0","OptimizedIE8","MSN\ Optimized","Creative\ AutoUpdate","Swapper");

      foreach($badmatches as $badstring){
        if(preg_match("/".$badstring."/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) return false;
      }

      // Now we'll go for positive matches

      $uamatches = array("midp", "j2me", "avantg", "docomo", "novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", "240x320", "opwv", "chtml", "pda", "windows\ ce", "mmp\/", "blackberry", "mib\/", "symbian", "wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi", "phone", "cdm", "up\.b", "audio", "SIE\-", "SEC\-", "samsung", "HTC", "mot\-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony", "alcatel", "lg", "erics", "vx", "NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", "panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch", "rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", "pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", "bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",     "sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "\d\d\di", "moto","webos");

      foreach($uamatches as $uastring){
        if(preg_match("/".$uastring."/i",$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) return true;
      }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Source: http://www.brainhandles.com/techno-thoughts/detecting-mobile-browsers